# Create random time in Swift

Tags: swift

trying to create a random “time” on iOS. So when a user presses a button a random time is displayed.

So far I have 2 labels that generate random numbers

1. For hours
2. Mins

For the hour Label; how can I add “0” to Int’s lower than 10? I.e 8 -> 08

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? And clarify what exactly you mean by "random time"?

Comment: Sorry just undated the question

Comment: Well, you could use a `TimeInterval` instead and then use something like a `DateComponentsFormatter` to format it (or even `DateComponents`, but I'm just thinking off the top of my head)

Comment: *"For the hour Label; how can I add “0” to Int’s lower than 10? I.e 8 -> 08"* - [swift zero pad string](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swift+zero+pad+string&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can use String with format to add the zero padding:

`let text = String(format: "%02i:%02i", hours, minutes) //Assumes hours and minutes are integers`

Answer (score 0):

I like number formatter for this sort of thing, just because it's a little more readable than string with format. And then to get random times of day, just use the class method on Int.

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let temp = NumberFormatter()
    temp.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
    return temp
}()

let minutes = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int.random(in: 1...59)))
let hour = Int.random(in: 1...12)
let timeSuffix = Bool.random() ? "PM" : "AM"

if let min = minutes {
    let randomTime = "\(hour):\(min) \(timeSuffix)"
}
```

I did the same thing to create a time suffix (AM/PM).